# This is part of a hash table implementation with Nodes but I don't understand how would you implement this method?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, hashtable

This is part of a hash table implementation with Nodes but I don't understand how would you implement this method?

```
//Convert a name to a key using radix-26:
//Use all of the letters of the alphabet as your digits.
//Assume we only deal with lower-case letters for simplicity.
//Then you can create the radix(base)-26 alphabet number system.
//For example:
// "alice" in radix-26 is 26^4*1 + 26^3*12 + 26^2*9 + 26^1*3 + 26^0*5 = 674055
// "zoe" in radix-26 is 26^2*26 + 26^1*15 + 26^0*5 = 17971 


public static long nameToKey(String name) {
    long key = 0;
    /**
     * TODO
     */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Notice that `alice` maps to `26^4*1 + 26^3*12 + 26^2*9 + 26^1*3 + 26^0*5` where the numbers `1, 12, 9, 3, 5` are the positions of the letters `a, l, i, c, e` in the alphabet. Does that answer your question, or are you stuck on something else? Please edit the question to be more specific - "I don't understand" isn't really a question.

Comment: oh, ok. I think that answers it? Thank you!